# jQuery, issue with slideToggle

Tags: jquery, function, slidetoggle

When my mouse is over a div .test I want a div .box to come above .test with slideToggle, and when the mouse is leaving .test I want .box to slideToggle again.

It's working well but when I'm moving the mouse in the top-left of .test it doesn't seem to work I don't know why...

My css is:

```
.box{
    z-index:2;
    position: absolute;
}
```

and my jQuery:

```
box = function(el) {
    $('body').append('<div class="box"></div>');
    var box = $('.box:last');
    var posTop = el.offset().top;
    var posLeft = el.offset().left;
    box.hide().css({
        'left': posLeft,
        'top': posTop
 }).html('azerty<br>azerty<br>azerty<br>azerty<br>azerty<br>azerty<br>azerty').slideToggle(150);
}

boxStop = function() {
    var box = $('.box:last');
    box.stop().slideToggle(150, function() {box.remove();});
}

$(document).on('mouseover', '.test', function() {
    box($(this));
}).on('mouseout', function() {
    boxStop();
});
```

here a fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/malamine_kebe/sKNcs/3/

Comment: It's because the element that slides down suddenly appears where your mouse pointer is, and that triggers the mouseleave event on the original element, and it slides up again, common mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing the z-index of `.box` to -1, so it is not covering `.test` and blocking the mouseover.

```
.box{
    position: absolute;
    z-index: -1;
}
```

Here's the [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dopernicus/kR9Bn/).

EDIT: Since a negative z-index will make the element be behind all other elements (which you might not want), you could also position `.test` and make sure that it has a higher z-index than `.box`.

```
.box{
    position: absolute;
}

.test {
    z-index: 1;
    position: absolute; /*could be relative or fixed too*/
}
```

And the [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dopernicus/82M4X/).

Comment: thanks, it's working perfectly. Any idea how can I stop the slideToggle when the mouse is over .box?

Answer (score 0):

The box comes up and then the mouse is not over your div.test anymore but over div.box.

You can add "pointer-events:none;" to your css:

```
.box{
  z-index:2;
  position: absolute;
  pointer-events:none;
}
```

But that will only work in new browsers.